# Bash Script pass a Variable as inside quotes for curl XPOST command

Tags: shell-script, curl

I am writing a bash script to invoke a curl command:

```
#!/bin/bash

while n flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        n) name=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done
curl -XPOST http://localhost:2468/api/webhook -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{"name":"'"$name"'"}'
```

However, this is not parsing the variable and sending an empty string. I get the same result when I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

while u:p:n flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        u) unrar=${OPTARG};;
        p) path=${OPTARG};;
        n) name=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done

curl -XPOST http://localhost:2468/api/webhook -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data "{/"name/":/"$name/"}"
```

Comment: Your issue does not seem to be the actual `curl` command but with the `while` loop that attempts to parse the script's arguments. Are you showing the actual code you are running, and are you getting error messages from the script? Please update the question with the code you are running, the way you invoke the script, and the verbatim output of the script when you run it.

Comment: `n` and especially `u:p:n` appear somewhat unlikely to be the names of existing commands, so I'd expect `while n flag` and/or `while u:p:n flag` to give you errors in the order of "command not found". If you get such an error, it should be an indicator of an immediate problem. Even if you don't get an error, it'd help the readers help you if you showed what, exactly, happens and also what exactly you _expect_ to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `getopts` to read script parameters:

```
while getopts "u:p:n:" flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        u) unrar=${OPTARG};;
        p) path=${OPTARG};;
        n) name=${OPTARG};;
    esac
done
```

Also, do not forget a colon after "n" if you want an argument for it. Without a colon `-n` would work as a binary key yes/no.

Comment: Also note that this assumes that the option-argument to `-n` is a JSON-encoded string.

Comment: Thank you! that was it, I cant believe how careless i was with this!